# how to make a copy of a class in python?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-2.x, metaclass

I have a class `A`

```
class A(object):
    a = 1
    def __init__(self):
      self.b = 10 
    def foo(self):
      print type(self).a
      print self.b
```

Then I want to create a class `B`, which equivalent as `A` but with different name and value of class member `a`:

This is what I have tried:

```
  class A(object):
    a = 1 
    def __init__(self):
      self.b = 10
    def foo(self):
      print type(self).a
      print self.b

  A_dummy = type('A_dummy',(object,),{})
  A_attrs = {attr:getattr(A,attr)  for attr in dir(A) if (not attr in dir(A_dummy))}

  B = type('B',(object,),A_attrs)
  B.a = 2 

  a = A() 
  a.foo()

  b = B() 
  b.foo()
```

However I got an Error:

```
  File "test.py", line 31, in main
    b.foo()
TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

So How I can cope with this sort of jobs (create a copy of an exists class)? Maybe a meta class is needed? But What I prefer is just a function `FooCopyClass`, such that:

```
B = FooCopyClass('B',A)
A.a = 10
B.a = 100

print A.a # get 10  as output
print B.a # get 100 as output
```

In this case, modifying the class member of `B` won't influence the `A`, vice versa.

Comment: Note: The fact that you're on Python 2 is important here; on Python 3, you wouldn't have the problem with unbound methods because there are no such things (you can copy a function from one class to another without it complaining when you use it with the new class in most cases, the exception being cases where no-arg `super()` is used, thanks to some magic involved in making no-arg `super()` work).

Comment: Don't use `dir` just copy the entirety of `vars(A)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: That would also likely bypass the descriptor protocol issues that are causing the unbound method problems. You'd need to use `vars(A).copy()` though, so you could edit the value of `'a'` in the resulting `dict` without changing `A` (you can't actually change the result without copying, thanks to it being a `dictproxy`/`mappingproxy` that prohibits reassignment).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I got the same error when I use `A_attrs = {attr:getattr(A,attr) for attr in vars(A)}`

Comment: @springcc don't use `getattr`, use `B = type("B", (object,), dict(vars(A)))`. Note, note every class will have a `__dict__`, they may have `__slots__` instead, in which case, you'll need to copy that manually.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Your method works! I used `A_attrs = vars(A).copy()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that looking up a method attribute on a Python 2 class creates an unbound method, it doesn't return the underlying raw function (on Python 3, unbound methods are abolished, and what you're attempting would work just fine). You need to bypass the descriptor protocol machinery that converts from function to unbound method. The easiest way is to use `vars` to grab the class's attribute dictionary directly:

```
# Make copy of A's attributes
Bvars = vars(A).copy()
# Modify the desired attribute
Bvars['a'] = 2
# Construct the new class from it
B = type('B', (object,), Bvars)
```

Equivalently, you could copy and initialize `B` in one step, then reassign `B.a` after:

```
# Still need to copy; can't initialize from the proxy type vars(SOMECLASS)
# returns to protect the class internals
B = type('B', (object,), vars(A).copy())
B.a = 2
```

Or for slightly non-idiomatic one-liner fun:

```
B = type('B', (object,), dict(vars(A), a=2))
```

Either way, when you're done:

```
B().foo()
```

will output:

```
2
10
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to (1) create copies of classes for some reason for some real app: 
in that case, try using `copy.deepcopy` - it includes the mechanisms to copy classes. Just change the copy `__name__` attribute afterwards if needed. Works both in Python 2 or Python 3.

(2) Trying to learn and understand about Python internal class organization: in that case, there is no reason to fight with Python 2, as some wrinkles there were fixed for Python 3.

In any case, if you try using `dir` for fetching a class attributes, you will end up with more than you want - as dir also retrieves the methods and attributes of all superclasses. So, even if your method is made to work (in Python 2 that means getting the `.im_func` attribute of retrieved unbound methods, to use as raw functions on creating a new class), your class would have more methods than the original one.

Actually, both in Python 2 and Python 3, copying a class `__dict__` will suffice. If you want mutable objects that are class attributes not to be shared, you should resort again to `deepcopy`. In Python 3:

```
class A(object):
    b = []
    def foo(self):
      print(self.b)

from copy import deepcopy

def copy_class(cls, new_name):
   new_cls = type(new_name, cls.__bases__, deepcopy(A.__dict__))
   new_cls.__name__ = new_name
   return new_cls
```

In Python 2, it would work almost the same, but there is no convenient way to get the explicit bases of an existing class (i.e. `__bases__` is not set). You can use `__mro__` for the same effect. The only thing is that all ancestor classes are passed in a hardcoded order as bases of the new class, and in a complex hierarchy  you could have differences between the behaviors of `B` descendants and `A` descendants if multiple-inheritance is used.